# selecting checkboxes as a group

Tags: jquery

I currently use the code below to loop through checkboxes.  It works, however it's getting every single checkbox on my page.  Is there a way to only select a certain group of checkboxes that share the same name, class, or exist in the same div container?

Thanks

```
 $('input[type=checkbox]').each(function () {
 ...do stuff
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Filtering by name :

```
$('input[type=checkbox][name=yourname]')
```

or

```
$('input[type=checkbox]').filter('[name=yourname]')
```

Filtering by class

```
$('input[type=checkbox]').filter('.myclass')
```

Filtering by parent :

```
$('input[type=checkbox]', parent)
```

Answer (score 2):

at the same div (assuming it has a class):

```
$('.theclassofthediv input[type=checkbox]').each(function () {
```

Answer (score 2):

filter by name:

```
$('input[type=checkbox][name=name]')
```

filter by class

```
$('input[type=checkbox]').filter('.myclass').each(..)
```

Answer (score 1):

Filtering by class, directly in the selector without using `.filter()`:

```
$('input.myclass[type=checkbox]');
```